# Vertical align (inline, middle) divs with image and text

Tags: css, inline, vertical-alignment

I just want to align two divs next to each other and aligning the content vertically middle in each. Any help could save my mental health. Here is my code:

```css
.main-kozossegitag-container {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.main-kozossegitag-text1 {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 60%;
 height: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: right;
}

.main-kozossegitag-nev {
 font-size: 2em;
}

.main-kozossegitag-title {
 font-size: 1em;
}

.main-kozossegitag-visszhang {
 font-size: 1em;
}

.main-kozossegitag-image1 {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 39%;
}

.profilkep {
    max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 3px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-kozossegitag-container">
  <div class="main-kozossegitag-text1">
    <h3 class="main-kozossegitag-nev">Rita</h3>
    <p class="main-kozossegitag-title">CEO</p>
    <p class="main-kozossegitag-visszhang">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="main-kozossegitag-image1">
    <img src="http://www.kaptarcoworking.hu/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/szabo_rita.jpg" alt="Szabó Rita" class="profilkep">
  </div>
</div>
```

As you see the two divs are next to each other, but I can not align the text vertically in the middle :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.main-kozossegitag-container {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.main-kozossegitag-text1 {
 display: table-cell;
    vertical-align : middle;
 width: 60%;
 height: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: right;
  
}

.main-kozossegitag-nev {
 font-size: 2em;
    
}

.main-kozossegitag-title {
 font-size: 1em;
}

.main-kozossegitag-visszhang {
 font-size: 1em;
}

.main-kozossegitag-image1 {
 display: table-cell;
  vertical-align : middle;
 width: 39%;
  
}

.profilkep {
    max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 3px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-kozossegitag-container">
  <div class="main-kozossegitag-text1">
    <h3 class="main-kozossegitag-nev">Rita</h3>
    <p class="main-kozossegitag-title">CEO</p>
    <p class="main-kozossegitag-visszhang">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="main-kozossegitag-image1">
    <img src="http://www.kaptarcoworking.hu/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/szabo_rita.jpg" alt="Szabó Rita" class="profilkep">
  </div>
</div>
```

I added `display : table;` to your main container (`main-kozossegitag-text1`) and `display : table-cell; vertical-align : middle` to your both sub-div. Those properties let them have the same behaviour as a table and cells that contains vertically aligned content. I just messed up with some left/right margin but the rest seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Add Vertical-align to the second Div.

```
.main-kozossegitag-image1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 39%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/s66rLcq2/).

I used CSS3 flex-box model. I changed properties for these classes:

```
.main-kozossegitag-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.main-kozossegitag-text1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    align-content: flex-end;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 60%;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

More on CSS3 flex-box [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score -1):

Just add a float-left to this div :

`.main-kozossegitag-text1{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align : middle;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
}`

Comment: How does `float:left` help at all?